# ShareThis + GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, sharethis

I would like to manually push sharethis data into GTM.

```
dataLayer.push({
              'event': 'event', 
              'socialNetwork': 'network', 
              'socialAction': 'action', 
              'socialTarget': 'pageurl'
          });
```

How do I intercept the native send/push ?

has anyone done that or something similar.
Any direction/help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what you mean by "manually push"? excuted this in your code then you have the data in gtm

Comment: You have to supply data layer into event and it'll work smoothly.